# Mostrar botones por condición

Tags: php

Utilizo PHP 7.3 con MySQL. Me encuentro desarrollando una pagina web la cual muestra información de una base de datos propia.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿puede hacerse una iteración la cual me permita mostrar desplegables *dropdown* según un contador que recojo de la base de datos?

Ésta es la parte que me gustaría iterar:

```
 <li class="nav-item dropright">
    <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright"aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Pongo la idea en pseudocódigo:

```
var counter=5;
var i=0
while(counter>i){
    mostrar_boton(i);
    i++;

}
accion mostrar_boton(entero i){
    <li class="nav-item dropright">
        <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright"aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link "variable i"</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>

}
```

Quiero hacer un bucle para no repetir código, si no tendré que hacer `case` o `if`/`else` y el código se me haría muy largo.

El resultado debería ser algo así:
[image: Resultado de menús desplegables]

Comment: Y que has intentado? Cuál resultado esperas? Se más especifico por favor.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta, espero que asi quede mas claro.

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. Supongo que lo que quieres es traer `N` cantidad de filas y usarlas para construir tus `li`. Esa es una tarea habitual en bases de datos. Intenta el código, o sea, conectar, consultar, leer resultados y construir los `li` y donde tengas problemas nos dices: **tengo problema aquí**. Con un seudo código no podemos responder a tu pregunta, por varios motivos: no sabemos qué consulta habrá que lanzar, no sabemos si usarás PDO o mysqli para conectar, etc, etc. Hace falta un punto de partida y eso te corresponde a ti.

Comment: Es que no se ni por donde empezar, y no es eso lo que quiero, de la base de datos solo cojo un numero entero que vendria a ser la variable counter. Solo quiero mostrar x cantidad de dropdowns segun la variable x. Un while que me muestre el codigo html segun una variable. No tiene relacion con la base de datos, aunque el codigo esta hecho por otros motivos en una pagina .php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de hacer en PHP lo que describes en el pseudocódigo es:

```
<?php
$counter = 5;
$i = 0;
while ($counter > $i) {
    mostrar_boton($i);
    $i++;
}

function mostrar_boton($i) {
?>    <li class="nav-item dropright">
        <a class="nav-link dropright-toggle" href="" id="navbarDroprightMenuLink" data-toggle="dropright"aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown link <?= $i ?></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php
}
```

Dentro de la función realizo una salida de PHP con `?>` para que en cada llamada a la función se envíe ese HTML al navegador, luego vuelvo a entrar en PHP con `<?php`. Dentro del HTML uso `<?= $i ?>` como versión corta de `<?php echo $i; ?>` para enviar al navegador el contenido de la variable.

Recuerda que si la variable `$i` tuviera contenido fuera de tu control (que pudiera contener HTML, por ejemplo por obtenerlo de la base de datos o recibirlo desde un formulario de usuario) debes hacer uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) de la siguiente manera: `<?= htmlspecialchars($i) ?>` para evitar problemas de seguridad ([XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).